# How to execute \LTXexample repeatitively with a looping macro such that its counter value gets rendered in both input/output parts?

Tags: showexpl

The following code is the simplified version of my real scenario. It might look trivial.

*I forgot to say that the following code is the Minimal Not Working Example (MNWE):*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\newcount\counter
\counter=-1
\loop
    \advance \counter by 1
    \ifnum\counter<5
    \LTXexample
        \scalebox{\counter}{\counter}
    \endLTXexample
    \newpage
\repeat
\end{document}
```

When `\counter=1`, for example, I want the input part (source part) to get rendered as

```
\scalebox{1}{1}
```

rather than

```
\scalebox{\counter}{\counter}
```

.

Error messages when it is compiled with pdflatex, latex, xelatex:

```
(c:/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)

Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 21.


(c:/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd))
*
! Emergency stop.
<*> counterlistings

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on counterlistings.log.
```

How to execute `\LTXexample` repeatitively with a looping macro such that its counter value gets rendered in both input/output parts?

Comment: About the MNWE: Note that all MWE (of questions, not answers) should "not work", so they can show the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `\loop` reads everything till `\repeat` as argument and therefore doesn't allow verbatim environments like `LTXexample`:

```
\loop:
\long macro:#1\repeat ->\def \iterate {#1\relax \expandafter \iterate \fi }\iterate \let \iterate \relax
```

You need to look for a different way to loop over it.
Note that `showexpl` uses `listings` which allows for escape characters. You could use these to escape around the counter value and have `\number\counter` there. This should write the number to the temp file.

Comment: Only the first two lines of your answer are understandable. The remaining ones are difficult to understand even I read multiple times. :-)

Comment: Simply open the `listings` manual and search for `escape`! :-) Anyway, this doesn't work for write-to-file listings. They escape characters are then ignored :-(

Comment: OK. I read the manual until page 24 yesterday. I will continue the remaining later. I will decide whether or not I should execute the green mark on this answer later after grasping the knowledge. :-)