# Table with Tabu & siunitx not working

Tags: siunitx, tabu

I am trying to make a table with tabu and using the sunitx package to align and round the entries of my table. However I keep getting the following error:

> ! siunitx error: "unknown-option" ! ! Unknown option 'm'. ! ! See the
>   siunitx documentation for further information.

My MNWE (minimal not-working example)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}             
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype Z{ XS[m,
 tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,
                          round-precision=2] }
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\small
\caption{Caption}\label{tab:exAll}
\begin{tabu}{X[m,l] ZZZZZZZZ}  
\toprule
{}&{A}&{B}&{C}&{D}&{E}&{F}&{G}&{H}\\
\midrule
case 1&0.038941&    10.793553&  10.793553&  2.660292&   5.364928&   0.287945&   4.950661&   1.017396\\
case 2&0.051109&    10.416524&10.416524&    2.699890&5.236410&  0.348350&   5.528117&   0.835394\\
case 3&0.042755&    11.165675&11.165675&    2.845072&   6.585281&   0.279750&   5.059948&   0.920121\\
case 4&0.043165&    10.820561   &10.820561& 2.708484&   5.250033&   0.291793&   4.661221&   0.879731\\
case 5&0.042951&13.764616&13.764616&    2.643305&   5.608317&   0.278537&   5.080898&   0.871181\\
case 6&0.042078&    10.909180   &10.909180& 2.568346&   5.198260&   0.311224&   4.724302&   0.862366\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I solve this problem?
I looked at similar questions here on tex.se but those didn't help me. I hope I am not overlooking something very simple.

Comment: I like the introduction of the term MNWE to TeX.SX.

Comment: @Ingo: Yes, thank user “xport” :-) See http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=mnwe%20is%3aquestion. The oldest evidence is [How to execute \LTXexample repeatitively with a looping macro such that its counter value gets rendered in both input/output parts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25492).

Comment: Haha, what a great community we have `:-)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your new column definition to

```
\newcolumntype{Z}{S[
 tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,
                          round-precision=2] }
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{Z}{S[
 tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,
                          round-precision=2] }
\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\caption{Caption}\label{tab:exAll}
\begin{tabu}{X[m,l] ZZZZZZZZ}
\toprule
{}&{A}&{B}&{C}&{D}&{E}&{F}&{G}&{H}\\
\midrule
case 1&0.038941&    10.793553&  10.793553&  2.660292&   5.364928&   0.287945&   4.950661&   1.017396\\
case 2&0.051109&    10.416524&10.416524&    2.699890&5.236410&  0.348350&   5.528117&   0.835394\\
case 3&0.042755&    11.165675&11.165675&    2.845072&   6.585281&   0.279750&   5.059948&   0.920121\\
case 4&0.043165&    10.820561   &10.820561& 2.708484&   5.250033&   0.291793&   4.661221&   0.879731\\
case 5&0.042951&13.764616&13.764616&    2.643305&   5.608317&   0.278537&   5.080898&   0.871181\\
case 6&0.042078&    10.909180   &10.909180& 2.568346&   5.198260&   0.311224&   4.724302&   0.862366\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `round-precision=3`, you get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in this solution (unlike [the other one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162245/15874)), the numbers are both aligned and centered in each column.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
%  locale = DE, % comma as decimal separator
  tight-spacing = true,
  round-mode = places
}

\def\precision{2} % change this value to suit your needs
\newcolumntype{Y}{S[table-format = 2.\precision, round-precision = \precision]}
\newcolumntype{Z}{S[table-format = 1.\precision, round-precision = \precision]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
 \centering
 \small
  \caption{An extremely relevant caption.}
  \label{tab:exAll}
    \begin{tabular}{l @{\qquad} Z *{2}{Y} *{5}{Z}}
     \toprule
             & {A}      & {B}       & {C}       & {D}      & {E}      & {F}      & {G}      & {H}      \\
     \midrule
      Case~1 & 0.038941 & 10.793553 & 10.793553 & 2.660292 & 5.364928 & 0.287945 & 4.950661 & 1.017396 \\
      Case~2 & 0.051109 & 10.416524 & 10.416524 & 2.699890 & 5.236410 & 0.348350 & 5.528117 & 0.835394 \\
      Case~3 & 0.042755 & 11.165675 & 11.165675 & 2.845072 & 6.585281 & 0.279750 & 5.059948 & 0.920121 \\
      Case~4 & 0.043165 & 10.820561 & 10.820561 & 2.708484 & 5.250033 & 0.291793 & 4.661221 & 0.879731 \\
      Case~5 & 0.042951 & 13.764616 & 13.764616 & 2.643305 & 5.608317 & 0.278537 & 5.080898 & 0.871181 \\
      Case~6 & 0.042078 & 10.909180 & 10.909180 & 2.568346 & 5.198260 & 0.311224 & 4.724302 & 0.862366 \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is choose the value of `\precision` and the table will automatically be typeset correct.